# Failed Triage audit - disagree with reason

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7723743

I voted to close the above question as primarily opinion based, because according to the site's criteria for asking questions, it is. An alternative would've been to send it to Code Review, but either way, I don't feel that this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow. However others (including those who upvoted the question and its answers) clearly disagree.

Is my understanding correct or incorrect?

Comment: "_Are there other ways to achieve the same result?_" I don't think this is primarily opinion based. If it had been "_What is the best way ?_" Then that would have been off-topic. It's about programming, it's clear, it's not really too opinion based, so it is OK imo. But yes, you could flag for mod attention and ask for it to be migrated to Code Review.

Comment: Any mods out there?

Comment: I somewhat agree that this is a bad audit. The fact that the question and its answers is upvoted is not the indicator whether the question is on-topic (as already mentioned by [David Heffernan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118950/using-generics-to-create-an-interfaced-object#comment46482904_29118950)). The current revision is asking whether it's possible to achieve the same result, which I think is too broad without very specific requirement.